# Multi model saving, how to wrap in transaction and report errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a registration form model that takes the users input during registration:

```
class RegForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :company_name, :email, :password
    validates_presence_of # ...

end
```

During this registration process I have multiple models that need to be created, and I am not sure how to properly display error messages and how to bubble the model error messages back to the UI.

```
if @reg_form.valid?
   account = Account.create!(@reg_form)
else 
...
```

Account.create! looks like:

```
def self.create!(reg_form)
  account = Account.create_from_reg!(reg_form)
  location = location.create_from_reg!(account, reg_form)
  ..
  ..
  account.location = location
  ..
  account.save!

  account
end
```

1. So I'm confused how to display error messages for all these models that are saving
2. how to display or fail validation if the reg_form doesn't have the correct data for all the other models.
3. how to ensure this is wrapped in a transaction so I don't save anything if any model fails to save during registration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning.

We want our registration form object to have the same API as any other ActiveRecord model:

```
// view.html
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
<% end %>

# controller.rb
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)

  if @book.save
    redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

To do that, we create the following object:

```
class RegForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :company_name, :email, :password

  def save
    # Save Location and Account here
  end
end
```

Now, by including `ActiveModel::Model`, our `RegForm` gains a ton of functionality, including showing errors and validating attributes (yes, it's unnecessary to include `ActiveModel::Validations`). In this next step we add some validations:

```
validates :email, :password, presence: true
```

And we change `save` so that it **runs** those validations:

```
def save
  validate
  # Save Location and Account here
end
```

`validate` returns `true` if all validations pass and `false` otherwise.

`validate` also adds [errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) to the `@reg_form` (All ActiveRecord models have an `errors` hash which is populated when a validation fails). This means that in the view we can do any of these:

```
@reg_form.errors.messages
#=> { email: ["can't be blank"], password: ["can't be blank"] }

@reg_form.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Email can't be blank", "Password can't be blank"]

@reg_form.errors[:email]
#=> ["can't be blank"]

@reg_form.errors.full_messages_for(:email)
#=> ["Email can't be blank"]
```

Meanwhile, our `RegistrationsController` should look something like this:

```
def create
  @reg_form = RegForm.new(reg_params)

  if @reg_form.save
    redirect_to @reg_form, notice: 'Registration was successful'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

We can clearly see that when `@reg_form.save` returns `false`, the `new` view is re-rendered.

Finally, we change `save` so that our models `save` calls are wrapped inside a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
def save
  if valid?
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      location = Location.create!(location_params)
      account = location.create_account!(account_params)
    end
    true
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  # Handle database exceptions not covered by validations.
  # e.message and e.cause.message can help you figure out what happened
end
```

Points worthy of note:

1. `create!` is used instead of `create`. The [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) is only rolled back if an exception is raised (which methods with a bang usually do).
2. [`validate` is just an alias for `valid?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/valid%3F). To avoid all that indentation we could instead use a guard at the top of the `save` method:

   ```
   return if invalid?
   ```
3. We can turn a database exception ([like an email uniqueness constraint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuh9COzp5vo&t=19m15s)) into an error by doing something like:

   ```
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
     errors.add(:email, :taken)
   end
   ```
4. We can add an error not directly associated with an attribute by using the symbol [`:base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add):

   ```
   errors.add(:base, 'Company and Email do not match')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think transactions and error handling will help you solve your problem.

```
def save_or_rescue
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    account = Account.create_from_reg!(reg_form)
    location = location.create_from_reg!(account, reg_form)
    ...
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
  puts exception
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to display the exception, I want to display the validation errors from the other models.