# How to pass around model errors between multiple classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

What's an elegant way to handle passing around model errors through chains of classes?

Let's say I have a complex form with inputs `foo` and `bar` for which I want to display validation errors on the form. However, `foo` and `bar` themselves are not model inputs, they are just data passed to service classes:

```
class ComplexForm
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def save
    foo_processor.process(foo)
    bar_processor.process(bar)
  end
end
```

The processors then validate the inputs, validate the resulting model, and either save or return errors. The processors use `ActiveModel::Model`

```
class FooProcessor
  include ActiveModel::Model

  validate :foo_is_valid

  def process(foo)
    model_instance = MyModel.new(parse(foo))
    if valid? && model_instance.valid?
      model_instance.save
    else
      ???
    end
  end
end
```

How do I pass this potential chain of errors up to `ComplexForm` and attribute them to the right input?

Comment: Do you read about Concerns? (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Comment: [Found the answer here in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689867/multi-model-saving-how-to-wrap-in-transaction-and-report-errors/38810073#38810073)